# Calculating 3m annualised rates

Tags: inflation

Calculating 3m annualised rates is a concept I've been struggling with for some time, but I think the below example illustrates what I am looking at trying to understand.

The past 6 months of monthly YoY inflation data for Hungary has been as follows:

[image]

From which is has been calculated that the 3m annualised rate is as follows:

[image]

How is this number calculated on a rolling basis?

Comment: You can’t do it from YoY rates; you need the underlying index.

Comment: @BrianRomanchuk If you had MoM rates e.g. 0.7% 0.3% 0.4% how should it be calculated then?

Comment: Convert the three monthly rates to (1+r) form, then multiply the 3 terms, and you get (1 + r_3m). To annualize, take to the power 4.

Comment: (In the previous, I assume that the monthly rate is not annualised.)

Answer (score 1):

Let’s assume that the price index is denoted $p_t$, with $p_1$ the first month, and $p_4$ the fourth. To calculate the 3-month annualised rate between the 1st and 4th month, we note that :
$p_4 = (1 + r)^{\frac{1}{4}} p_1,$ where $r$ is the annualised inflation rate.

Or: $(1+r) = (\frac{p_4}{p_1})^4$.

We cannot calculate the price index level from the 12-month change data; you need either index levels or 1-month percentage changes.